# Trying to display data from database but getting repeated variable name instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and I'm having a few problems getting into the groove. 
I'm trying to display the users and their ID's, but I'm getting an error when I try to display the ID:

```
undefined method `id' for #<Person::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc86af3b080>
```

As a test, I removed the ID part and just displayed `p.name` twice, and this is the result:

```
Users

ID  User
Person  Person
Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person Person
```

I noticed if I do something like

```
<% p = Person.find(1) %>
<% p.name %>
```

I get back:

```
Billy
```

My third and last problem is the table, the first two records stay in the table, but the rest of them just flow across the screen. I don't use tables alot, this isn't as much of a problem to me, I'm sure I can figure this part out eventually.

The code I'm using for all of these problems to occur is below:

**index.html.erb**

## Users

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <% p = Person.all %>
    <% p.each do |person| %>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50px;"><%= p.id %></td>
            <td style="width: 50px;"><%= p.name %></td>
        </tr>
</table>


<% end %>
```

**person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name,
    presence: true
end
```

**Database:**

```
mysql> desc people;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from people;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Billy |
|  2 | Billy |
|  3 | Billy |
|  4 | Billy |
|  5 | Billy |
|  6 | Billy |
|  7 | Billy |
|  8 | Billy |
|  9 | Billy |
| 10 | Billy |
+----+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in view:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>User</th>
</tr>
<% p = Person.all %>
<% p.each do |person| %>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px;"><%= person.id %></td>
        <td style="width: 50px;"><%= person.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

`p` is an array of all persons
you should change `p.id` and `p.name` into `person.id` and `person.name`, because `person` represents one item from array in `each` loop

Comment: You fixed the table formatting, although I'm still getting the same output as before.

See pictures: http://i.gyazo.com/bcc4a2f44a5c295ab672b7b736b84720.png
http://i.gyazo.com/77ceababd1e905fa052c342d33a2869b.png

Comment: Based on the screenshot, you're referring to `Person.id` in your table column, when it should be lower-cased as `person.id`.

Comment: Happy to help. Your question was nicely documented, btw. (And it's nice to see a real account these days, versus user92415638396425. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1> Users </h1>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>User</th>
</tr>
<% p = Person.all %>
<% p.each do |person| %>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px;"><%= person.id %></td>
        <td style="width: 50px;"><%= person.name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

This made it work perfectly.
Thanks all.